# What ratio of students in a 20-student class with total average of 17.06 got at least 17?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, average

The maximum score is at most 20. The class has 20 students. For math exam the average of the whole class is 17.06. What percent of the class got at least 17 out of 20 in the exam?

Comment: Can students get non-integer scores? I assume so since $17.06 \cdot 20$ is not an integer.

Comment: Yes, Iranian scoring system works via scores over the range of 0-20 with two possible decimal places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:  It could be all of them.  They could all have scored $17.06$.  The minimum would be when some of the students scored $20$ and the rest scored just under $17$  How many would that be?  Your answer should be the range.

Comment: Can we solve this using a statistical distribution or something>

Comment: You don't need that.  If you have $n$ students with a perfect paper and the rest with $17$, the average is $\frac 1{20}(20n+(20-n)17)$  You are told this is $17.06$, so solve for $n$.  Then round up because $n$ must be integer-that will decrease the average score of those who didn't get a perfect paper.  Do you see why this minimizes the number who got at least $17$?  That is the point of the question.

Comment: I don't get the point

Comment: Do you see how my calculation gives the average of $n$ students scoring $20$ and $20-n$ students scoring $17$?

Comment: Feel free to put it as an answer so I could check it correct if you think it is the way it has got to be solved

Comment: Yes, calculation gives 17.45 for 3 scores of 17 and 17 scores of 20. but I don't know why it is so. Why does it work?

Comment: It is just taking the mean.  You add up all the scores and divide by the number, but instead of adding up $n\ 20$'s you multiply $20$ by $n$.